# Error using tool dissolve

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, dissolve

I am using the Dissolve tool to merge layer. I get the following error (translated from german):

*"Object (74207) has invalid geometry and was skipped. Please correct the geometry or change the processing setting to "Ignore invalid input objects" for this input or globally in the processing settings.
Object could not be written to Aufgel_st_7cd4e760_5b0a_4b32_97b4_57a6e723ebc3: Could not add object with geometry type GeometryCollection to layer of type MultiLineString
Could not write obect to OUTPUT
Execution failed after 0.03 seconds"*

I have modified the options but I still get the error. In the image I show in yellow the line and the table with data
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a tool in the toolbox. Its name is Fix Geometries, which fixes geometry errors automatically.

The answer is [here](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/handling_invalid_geometries.html#handling-invalid-geometries-qgis3).

Answer (score 0):

I found my data was in the wrong UTM zone and when reprojected into the correct zone the dissolve tool worked perfectly.  X value was about 810000 max should be about 620000

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).