Unable to dissolve
I want to dissolve a polygon layer (land use and cover), but when i try the dissolve,to eliminate the borders for the same selection, it says geometry invalid.
What should I do? 
Vector that I'm trying to dissolve

Have you tried the "Fix geometries"-tool?
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/448211/error-using-tool-dissolve

The error message indicates that there is a problem with the feature #6. You can try to find out what happened to this feature or you can try to repair the geometry of your whole vector layer using "Fix geometries".
